# VSTS release pipeline cant find released artifact

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to setup a CI/CD without much luck. My aim is to build a .net web project trough `VSTS` and deploy it to a `AWS Beanstalk` app.

Where am I so far?

Created a `vsts-ci.yml` file as following:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET web applications.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/vsts/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

And I have a build definition like below:

[image: build]

With this my first step `build` runs correctly. Btw Agent pool is `Hosted VS2017`.

Then I have created a release pipeline like below:

[image: release pipeline]

And as the Stage 1 tasks (the part that runs after artifact step), I have following:

[image: Release]

I have hooked the build to a master branch commit, and hooked the release to a successful build, these triggerings works correctly. Though it fails. The problem is caused by not found artifact files probably because of wrong path inputs. But I don't know the correct versions.

After build finishes, it claims it created a `.zip` file containing the published version:

[image: build-success]

But after this, the release fails, only by saying no such file. I have tried many paths at `Web Deploy Archive` field, but none of them could find the zip file.

[image: failed-release]

The powershell task you see, I created it to check the paths, and what they have in them, and they are mostly empty.

One interesting thing I figured is, build puts the files in `D:\a\1\a` but release tasks try to look into `D:\a\r1\a` when I suffixed the `Web Deploy Archive` field  with `$(System.defaultWorkingDirectory)` and `$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)`.

Another odd thing is that on release `Download artifact` stage, it says `Linked artifact count: 0`. Which I would expect to be something else.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? If someone can guide me trough, I would appreciate.

**Update:** I've added "Publish Artifact: drop"

When `Path to publish` is "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project-2-codes.zip"

> Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\r1\a\project-2-codes.zip

When `Path to publish` is "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"

> Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\r1\a\$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

Comment: You did add tasks to your build definition after you took the screenshot, right? Can you please describe how you configured your build tasks or publish the build log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of head banging to the walls, I've found out the problem.

I was creating the build definition all wrong. I have used the default wizard thing, without noticing the custom designer (I don't think the text next to the link and the name of the link makes any sence).

[image: build creation page]

And it was creating an almost empty build definition. I didn't even understood what it was doing. Now, using the `visual designer` I can actually select a buil definition template with all the required build tasks in it. After creating the build correctly, everything worked just nice.

Here is the build definition I came up with:

[image: build]

And here is the beanstalk deployment task:

[image: deployment]

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with the same issue for a couple of days and couldn't understand what was going on. What you highlighted with "use the visual designer" led me the right way. Because I still wanted to use the YAML template though, I did what you said then selected "Publish Artifact" then just above all the fields on the right, I clicked the link "View YAML" - it gave me the snippet I needed for fixing my original YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish your build outputs as an artifact. Use the `Publish Artifact` task.

Comment: Tried it, it still says "Not found PathToPublish". Please check updated question.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Just set  `Path to publish` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` and try it again.